# Prove a convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have to prove that if $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and $c \ge 0$ then $c \cdot f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex.

I know that function $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$  is convex if for $\forall x,y \in A$ and $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]:$ $f(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x)+ (1-\lambda)f(y)$, but I don't know how to use this in this prove.

Is it ok to say:

$f(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y) \le c \cdot f(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y)$

$\lambda f(x)+ (1-\lambda)f(y) \le  \lambda c \cdot f(x)+ (1-\lambda) c \cdot f(y)$

there for:

$c \cdot f(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y) \le \lambda c \cdot f(x)+ (1-\lambda) c \cdot f(y)$

Comment: "Is it ok to say..." No.  One problem is that If $c\geq 0$, that does not mean that $x\leq cx$ for all $x$.  For example if $x=1$ and $c=1/2$.  Another problem is that $w\leq x$, $y\leq z$, and $w\leq y$ does not imply $x\leq z$.

Comment: any help on how to prove this?

Comment: Matthew, Please see the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Since $c\geq 0$ and $f(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x)+ (1-\lambda)f(y)$, multiplying by $c$ we obtain:
$$ cf(\lambda x +(1- \lambda)y) \le \lambda cf(x)+ (1-\lambda)cf(y).$$
This is exactly the definition of $c.f$ is convex.